# how to properly call a function when it is a pointer to a class function but is outside that class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct, function-pointers

Sorry if that title is worded poorly... but here's what I'm trying to do...

I've got a struct "screen" that has a pointer to these functions that are members of class "Test"...

```
typedef struct screen{

     ...

     bool (Test::*drawfunc)(b2World*, objectdata*, actorlist*, camera*);    

     ...

}

class Test{

     ...

     screen* tscreen;

     bool Test::draw(b2World* world, objectdata* objects, actorlist* al, camera* cam);

     ...

}
```

I assign the drawfunc pointer in the creation of my Test instance "test" like this... and it looks weird to me, I don't completely understand it, but it compiles...

```
Test::Test()
{

     ...

     tscreen->drawfunc=&Test::draw;

     ...

}
```

but I can't figure out how to call the drawfunc function in my main... I'm trying it like this and it gives the error "error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 4 arguments"

```
int main (int acrgc, char** argv){

     ...

     Test* test = new Test();

     test->tscreen->drawfunc(test->m_world, test->objects, test->tscreen->al, test->tscreen->cam);

     ...

}
```

I know that call isn't right, I never specify which instance of class "Test" for drawfunc to work from... even though all the variables and the pointer to the function itself is from the instance "test"...

... and for the inevitable "Why are you trying to do this anyway?" reply... or in case there isn't a way to call that function or something... I really just want to be able to assign different functions to "drawfunc" and I want those functions to be able to use all the variables inside the instance "test", I can get it so drawfunc points to any old function (     bool (*drawfunc)(b2World*, objectdata*, actorlist*, camera*); ), but it needs to be able to access the other variables inside the Test instance "test". So... really just however you do that would be great too. Thanks.

Comment: Why not putting a bit of a simpler, but complete sample, that reflects your problem into your question. As it is it's quite hard to give you a correct answer for what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
(test ->* test->tscreen->drawfunc)(test->m_world, test->objects, test->tscreen->al, test->tscreen->cam);
```

In general, indirecting a pointer-to-member involves using the `->*` or `.*` operators.  If you have a pointer to an object `a` and a pointer-to-member `b`, then you would say `a ->* b`.  In your case, your pointer to an object is `test` and your pointer-to-member is `test->tscreen->drawfunc`.  Extra parentheses are necessary because `->*` is a binary operator, which has a lower precedence than the the postfix function call operator `()`, but you want to indirect the pointer-to-member before calling it.

Comment: WOW THANK YOU! I would've never figured that out. You sir are some kind of genius!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to not use function pointers directly and wrap it with functors like [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). In the case of member functions, use [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to bind the object into the functor:

```
struct foo
{
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "f()!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo my_foo;

    auto f_wrapper = std::bind( &foo::f , my_foo );

    f(); 
}
```

> f()!

This makes easy to pass different functions to a function or whatever else. For example:

```
class a_class_which_does_complex_drawings
{
    void draw();
};

void a_global_function_which_draws_things();


template<typename DRAW_FUNCT>
void the_function_which_really_draws( DRAW_FUNCT drawing_method )
{
    drawing_method(); //Tah dah!
}

int main()
{ 
    typedef std::function<void()> drawing_callback_t;
    std::vector<drawing_callback_t> callbacks;

    a_class_which_does_complex_drawings mi_complex_drawer;


    callbacks.push_back( a_global_function_which_draws_things ); //Works
    callbacks.push_back( std::bind( &a_class_which_does_complex_drawings::draw ,
                                    my_complex_drawer ) ); //Why not? Of course works

    callback.push_back( [](){ /* draw code */ } ); //Ohhh, a lambda! Also works

    //Simulation/Drawing/Game loop
    while( true )
    {
        for( auto& callback : callback )
            the_function_which_really_draws( callback ); //Magic, isn't?
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeDeSimone the lambda example could be removed, and I'm sure that `std::bind()` could be simulated easily. Or just use `boost::bind()`. The point is: **There are ways to make that kind of code clear, throwing away all of that pointer trickery.**

Comment: Sorry, this is all very confusing to me... i don't even know how to use cout or those "<<" operators completely. But, I need to assign drawfunc as test is being created (my 3rd block of code), at that point there's no test (instance of Test) to bind the function to. I guess my question for your answer is, how do you reference the object being created as its being created (so it can be binded)? Also, that seems like a weird work around, is there no way to call this function I'm trying to call?